# Remove controls wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I found this quite hard to find from searching but quite simply, how do you remove controls from a panel? I have some wxStaticText and wxTextCtrl and I want to swap delete the existing items and replace them with new ones? Is there some sort of command I can call or do I have to make something myself? Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: as ravenspoint pointed out, simply deleting the control is not enough. Some controls perform additional cleanup in `Destroy()`.

You can simply `Destroy()` the control. wxWidgets will automatically remove it from the parent window and free its memory.

```
wxWindow* ctrl = new wxStaticText(this);
ctrl->Destroy();
ctrl = new wxTextCtrl(this);
```

If you do not have a pointer to the control, you can use `FindWindowById`, `FindWindowByLabel` or `FindWindowByName` to obtain it:

```
if(wxWindow* ctrl = wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_MYCTRL,this))
    ctrl->Destroy();
```

If the control was added to a sizer, it has to be replaced while it is still valid:

```
newCtrl = new wxWindow(...);
sizer->Replace(oldCtrl,newCtrl); // both oldCtrl and newCtrl must be valid
oldCtrl->Destroy();
Layout(); // update sizer
```

Alternatively, you could create a wxTextCtrl from the start and make it read-only. However, additional style modifications would be required to make it look like a wxStaticText (for example the background color, border etc).

Comment: It is dangerous to simply call delete on the pointer.  You might end up with messages being sent to a deleted window.  It is better to call Destroy().

Comment: @ravenspoint You are correct. Some controls perform additional cleanup in `Destroy()` which is not done by the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to hide the widget.
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a7ed103df04014cb3c59c6a3fb4d95328

However, if you want to permanently remove the widget, then call Destroy http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a6bf0c5be864544d9ce0560087667b7fc